# Section snapping whilst scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement page/section snapping as you scroll page to page, for some reason the class="outer" seems to be interfering with the first page title, button and the nav bar? The nav bar was functional before I added the classes "outer" and "page" the title and button also remained on the first page and did not pass through to the other pages. anyone know what this problem is? have a feeling it's something simple

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}


@media (min-height: 30em) {
  .section__content > * {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 4rem, 0);
    transition: opacity 800ms var(--delay),
      transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.07, 0.26, 0.99) var(--delay);
  }
}

.is-visible .section__content > * {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 1rem, 0);
}
.is-visible .section__img {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

section {
    display: block;
    background: #CFF;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    
}
.background1 {

background: url("IMG-7323.GIF") no-repeat center center ;
background-size: cover; 
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

.outer {
  overflow-y:auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page {
  scroll-snap-align: start; height: 100vh;
}

#one {
    background: #111816;
    color: #fff;
    
}



/* Title section 1 */
.glow-on-hover {
    width: 220px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .glow-on-hover:before {
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      #ffffff,
      #969594,
      #ffffff,
      #969594,
      #ffffff,
      #969594,
      #ffffff,
      #969594,
      #ffffff
    );
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .glow-on-hover:active {
    color: #000;
  }

  .glow-on-hover:active:after {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .glow-on-hover:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .glow-on-hover:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(150, 167, 204);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  @keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 400% 0;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
  }

  h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-family: TaylorGothic;
    font-size: calc(20px + 5vw);
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.15em #1da9cc;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    filter: blur(0.007em);
    animation: shake 2.5s  infinite linear forwards;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: TaylorGothic;
  src: url(TaylorGothic.woff2);
}

@keyframes shake {
    5%, 15%, 25%, 35%, 55%, 65%, 75%, 95% {
        filter: blur(0.018em);
        transform: translateY(0.018em) rotate(0deg);
    }

    10%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 70%, 80%, 90% {
        filter: blur(0.01em);
        transform: translateY(-0.018em) rotate(0deg);
    }

    20%, 60% {
        filter: blur(0.03em);
        transform: translate(-0.018em, 0.018em) rotate(0deg);
    }

    45%, 85% {
        filter: blur(0.03em);
        transform: translate(0.018em, -0.018em) rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        filter: blur(0.007em);
        transform: translate(0) rotate(-0.5deg);
    }
}

@keyframes crack1 {
    0%, 95% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-51%, -48%);
    }
}

@keyframes crack2 {
    0%, 95% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-49%, -53%);
    }
}

  /* for the heading and the button alignment*/

  
  .btn-centering {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }


/*  section one end */



#two {
    background: #123037;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#three {
    background: #74BE98;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#four {
    background: #BED28D;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#five {
    background: #95211D;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">    <title></title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
    
    
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
 <nav> 
 <a href="#one">one</a>
 <a href="#two">two</a>
 <a href="#three">three</a>
 <a href="#four">four</a>
 <a href="#five">five</a>
</nav>
  
    

<div class="outer"> 
    <section id="one" > 

        <div class="page">

        <div class="background1"></div>

<!-- Title -->
           
        <div class="btn-centering">
            <h1 data-text="black mirror"><span>Ghosted</span></h1>
            <button class="glow-on-hover" onclick="location.href='products.html'" type="button">
            View Products</button></div>
            
<!-- Socail media buttons --> 




    </section>
    <section id="two">Page 2
      <div class="page"></div>

    </section>
    <section id="three">Page 3
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="four">Page 4
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="five">Page 5
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
 </div>
 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about how you want it to behave and what exactly it is doing wrong in your example. Please simplify your code for the question into an [mre]. This will not only help us, but it will also help you isolate the cause. Please take the time to write a good description with clear sentences, as you are asking people to take the time to solve your problem. Let me know when you've fixed it, so I can try and solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things,

Because `btn-centering` is not wrapped into any `position: relative` element, so it behaves like `position: fixed`, It was working for you previously because `.outer` didn't have `overflow`, `overflow` also affects **positions**

another thing is you have added `overflow-y: auto` to `.outer` so it has scroll now and `body` doesn't, but in jquery, you are trying to scroll the body.

1. I have added relative to `.page` element of first `.section`
2. I have added `z-index: 1` to `.nav` because the relative element is affecting `.nav`
3. I have changed `$('html,body').animate` to `$('.outer').animate`
4. After doing all the above changes the page was scrolling to wrong sections, I found that Jquery will change the **offset top** when the page scroll is changed, So I also changed `target.offset().top` to `target[0].offsetTop` (`target[0].offsetTop` is supported in all browsers including IE)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-height: 30em) {
  .section__content>* {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 4rem, 0);
    transition: opacity 800ms var(--delay), transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.13, 0.07, 0.26, 0.99) var(--delay);
  }
}

.is-visible .section__content>* {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 1rem, 0);
}

.is-visible .section__img {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

section {
  display: block;
  background: #CFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.background1 {
  background: url("IMG-7323.GIF") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.outer {
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
}

#one {
  background: #111816;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Title section 1 */

.glow-on-hover {
  width: 220px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #ffffff, #969594, #ffffff, #969594, #ffffff, #969594, #ffffff, #969594, #ffffff);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:active {
  color: #000;
}

.glow-on-hover:active:after {
  background: transparent;
}

.glow-on-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.glow-on-hover:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(150, 167, 204);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: TaylorGothic;
  font-size: calc(20px + 5vw);
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.15em #1da9cc;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  filter: blur(0.007em);
  animation: shake 2.5s infinite linear forwards;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: TaylorGothic;
  src: url(TaylorGothic.woff2);
}

@keyframes shake {
  5%,
  15%,
  25%,
  35%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  95% {
    filter: blur(0.018em);
    transform: translateY(0.018em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10%,
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  70%,
  80%,
  90% {
    filter: blur(0.01em);
    transform: translateY(-0.018em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  20%,
  60% {
    filter: blur(0.03em);
    transform: translate(-0.018em, 0.018em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  45%,
  85% {
    filter: blur(0.03em);
    transform: translate(0.018em, -0.018em) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0.007em);
    transform: translate(0) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
}

@keyframes crack1 {
  0%,
  95% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-51%, -48%);
  }
}

@keyframes crack2 {
  0%,
  95% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-49%, -53%);
  }
}


/* for the heading and the button alignment*/

.btn-centering {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*  section one end */

#two {
  background: #123037;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#three {
  background: #74BE98;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#four {
  background: #BED28D;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#five {
  background: #95211D;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title></title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('.outer').animate({
              scrollTop: target[0].offsetTop
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="#one">one</a>
    <a href="#two">two</a>
    <a href="#three">three</a>
    <a href="#four">four</a>
    <a href="#five">five</a>
  </nav>



  <div class="outer">
    <section id="one">

      <div class="page relative">

        <div class="background1"></div>

        <!-- Title -->

        <div class="btn-centering">
          <h1 data-text="black mirror"><span>Ghosted</span></h1>
          <button class="glow-on-hover" onclick="location.href='products.html'" type="button">
            View Products</button></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Socail media buttons -->




    </section>
    <section id="two">Page 2
      <div class="page"></div>

    </section>
    <section id="three">Page 3
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="four">Page 4
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="five">Page 5
      <div class="page"></div>
    </section>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```